# Is it possible to get results for various keys using curl for couchdb?

Tags: curl, couchdb

I have a key in key field in couchdb. where my key differs for each document. I need to get documents for various keys: say 1st key is "123123", 2nd key is "234234", I have to pass these in a single query and get results for both the keys using curl command.

In SQL we can do it as:

```
select * from table where user_id in "123123,234234";
```

Similarly I need to do this in couchdb using curl. Is this possible using curl command?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Answer (score 1):

Sure it is:

`curl -X POST http://localhost:5984/mydb/_design/users/_view/by_user_id -d '{"keys": ["123123", "234234"]}' -H "Content-Type: application/json"`

[More about CouchDB views query options](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_view_API#Querying_Options)

Comment: Kxepal : thanks for the help... but this doesn't work for me... its fetching all the results from that view....

Comment: @Ramesh , hm, probably you're right: tested it only for 1.3, which has better content type negotiation. Updated command by adding explicit content type header.